# React/React Native + Typescript Error: Cannot find name 'INSERT FUNCTION NAME HERE'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, typescript-typings

I'm just diving into Typescript and trying to implement it into one of my projects. However, I'm getting an error `Cannot find name 'selectValue'` when hovering over the `selectValue` method (See image below). Am I missing something in my tsconfig.json??

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "esnext",                       /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "lib": ["es6"],                           /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    "allowJs": true,                          /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    "jsx": "react-native",                    /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    // "outDir": "./",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    "noEmit": true,                           /* Do not emit outputs. */
    "incremental": true,                      /* Enable incremental compilation */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    "isolatedModules": true,                  /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,              /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node",               /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    "baseUrl": "./",                          /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    "typeRoots": [                            /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */

    ],
    "types": [                                /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
      "react",
      "react-native"
    ],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,     /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true                   /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "./",                    /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "./",                       /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "babel.config.js",
    "metro.config.js",
    "jest.config.js"
  ]
}
```

**Component:**

```
// Imports: Dependencies
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Dimensions, Platform, Picker, StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
// import DateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
Icon.loadFont();

// Screen Dimensions
const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');

// Component: List Picker
export const ListPicker = (props: object) => {
  // React Hooks: State
  const [ modalVisible, toggle ] = useState(false);
  const [ value, setValue ] = useState();

  // React Hooks: Lifecycle Methods

  // Toggle Modal
  toggleModal = () => {
    try {
      // Check Platform (iOS)
      if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        // React Hook: Toggle Modal
        toggle((modalVisible) => !modalVisible);
      }

      // Check Platform (Android)
      if (Platform.OS === 'android') {

      };
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  // Select Value
  selectValue = (value: string) => {
    try {
      // React Hook: Set Value
      setValue(value);

      // React Props: onValueChange
      props.onValueChange(value);
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  // Render Picker
  renderPicker = () => {
    try {
      return (
        <Picker
          selectedValue={value}
          onValueChange={this.selectValue}>
          {props.items.map((item: object) => {
            return (
              <Picker.Item
                label={item.label}
                value={item.value}
                key={item.key || item.label}
                color={item.color}
              />
            );
          })}
        </Picker>
      )
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.inputTitleContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.inputTitle}>{props.title}</Text>
      </View>

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleModal} style={styles.fieldTextContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.fieldText} numberOfLines={1}>{value !== undefined ? value : 'Select'}</Text>

        <Icon name="ios-arrow-forward" size={22} style={styles.arrowForward}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <Modal isVisible={modalVisible} style={styles.modal}>
        <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
          <View style={styles.pickerHeaderContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleModal} >
              <Text style={styles.doneText}>Done</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.pickerContainer}>
            {this.renderPicker()}
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
}

// Styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    width: width - 32,
    marginLeft: 16,
    marginRight: 16,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  modal: {
    margin: 0,
  },
  modalContainer: {
    height: '100%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },
  pickerHeaderContainer: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: 40,
    width: width,
    backgroundColor: '#FAFAF8',
    borderColor: '#7D7D7D',
    borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
  },
  pickerContainer: {
    height: 220,
    width: width,
    // backgroundColor: '#CFD3D9',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  doneText: {
    fontFamily: 'System',
    color: '#007AFF',
    fontWeight: '600',
    fontSize: 17,
    marginRight: 16,
  },
  stateContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: 75,
    borderColor: '#7D7D7D',
    borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
  },
  inputTitleContainer: {
    width: 75,
    marginBottom: 4,
  },
  inputTitle: {
    color: '#7D7D7D',
    borderColor: '#7D7D7D',
    fontSize: 10,
    fontWeight: '600',
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
  },
  fieldTextContainer: {
    height: 40,
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: 4,
    borderColor: '#7D7D7D',
    borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,    
  },
  fieldText: {
    width: width - 32 - 20,
    fontFamily: 'System',
    fontSize: 17,
    fontWeight: '400',
    color: '#000000',
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
  arrowForward: {
    color: 'black',
    opacity: .3,
    marginRight: 7,
  },
});
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare variables. You never declared `selectValue`, and it's not a property on an object (You are not working in a class, you can't say `this.selectValue` though `this` does exist on a different scope than you are expecting).

So you could do: `const selectValue = ...` or you could do

```
let selectValue: (value: string) => void;
selectValue = ...
```

or `const selectValue: (value: string) => void = ...`

I have a feeling someone downvoted this because you need to do some beginner research on TypeScript (don't get demotivated! It's a process of trying and reading). It's not a bad question, and I disagree with the downvote. But I do recommend reading a bit about the basics of typescript and javascript. What is an object vs a function, what's a property, method, etc.

I often try something, fail, then read about it (with the StackOverflow post when I don't know where to start). Without trying (for me), the reading doesn't make sense.